# Enclosing/Nested interfaces in Java

Tags: java

While looking through the code of javax.servlet.ServletRegistration interface, 
I have come across an enclosing interface (concept in Java) i.e., "interface Dynamic extends ServletRegistration, Registration.Dynamic" is the enclosing interface for ServletRegistration interface.

I am not clear on the below points on enclosing interfaces in Java

Could you please help ?

(1) How they are different from writing two separate/individual files/interfaces, like below ?

**Java Class File 1:**

```
interface ServletRegistration {
  m1();
  m2();
}
```

**Java Class File 2:**

```
interface interface Dynamic extends ServletRegistration, Registration.Dynamic {
  m3();
  m4();
}
```

How this is different from enclosing ?

(2) In the above example, anyone who implements ServletRegistration interface, do they need to implement enclosing interface (interface Dynamic) methods as well ?

(3) When do we go for enclosing interfaces ? I have not used them so far in any of my projects.

(4) What is the difference between nested vs enclosing interface ? Could you please give an example ?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding nested vs enclosing - they are opposite terms. If interface X is enclosing interface Y, you can say that Y is nested inside X.

Comment: A common example of a nested/enclosing interface pair would be ```Map.Entry```/```Map```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you mixed the terms. `Dynamic` is not an "enclosing interface for ServletRegistration interface", it is nested inside the `ServletRegistration`. You could say that `ServletRegistration` is enclosing `ServletRegistration.Dynamic`.

A nested interface is similar to nested static classes. It can be implemented independently of the interface in which it is nested.

In your example, nesting the `Dynamic` interface allows to define two different `Dynamic` interfaces in the same package - `javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic` and `javax.servlet.Registration.Dynamic` - you can't extract both of these interfaces to be top level interfaces in the same package with the same name.

Other than that, extracting the nested interfaces into top level interfaces makes no difference, just like doing the same with nested static classes wouldn't make a difference.

> When do we go for enclosing interfaces ?

The question would be clearer if you phrase it as `when do we nest interfaces inside other interfaces?` The answer - whenever it makes sense logically. For example, if interface X has methods that return interface Y, and no other interfaces use interface Y, it might make sense to declare interface Y as a nested interface of interface X.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide an example for Nested vs Enclosing interface ?

Comment: @developer `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` is nested inside `ServletRegistration`. `ServletRegistration` encloses `ServletRegistration.Dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

`interface Dynamic extends ServletRegistration, Registration.Dynamic` means that the interface `Dynamic` extends both the others, i.e. is like a combination of the two. Any non-abstract class that implements `Dynamic` implicitly also has to implement `ServletRegistration` *and* `Registration.Dynamic` while other classes can only implement one of the two.

> How they are different from writing two separate/individual interfaces ?

The difference is that if a class implements `Dynamic` you *know* that it also implements the other two interfaces while if you use them separately you don't.

> In the above example, anyone who implements ServletRegistration interface, do they need to implement enclosing interface (interface Dynamic) methods as well ?

No, if a class just implements `ServletRegistration` it doesn't have to implement `Dynamic`. If you switch that, i.e. if a class implements `Dynamic` is *has* to either be abstract or implement `ServletRegistration` as well (albeit that's implicit).

> When do we go for enclosing interfaces ? I have not used them so far in any of my projects.

I'm not sure that your usage of the term "enclosing" is correct here so I can't comment on that (I suspect you either mixed that up with something else or are applying a non-Java term). But since you seem to mean interface A extending *both* interface B and C (i.e. `interface A extends B,C`), I'll try to answer that:

Normally you'll want to decouple interfaces, i.e. you want to either deal with implementations of interface B or C. However, there may be cases where you want to ensure that a class you are using implements both (e.g. if a method has to call methods declared in B and C) so you could declare another interface that combines both (e.g. interface A) and require the parameters to implement that.

With the introduction of generics you could use something like `T extends B & C` to make sure of that but that's a newer addition compared to interfaces and legacy/non-generic code won't use that. Additionally you might have to declare a combining interface if you want to add additional methods and want to enforce the other interfaces to be implemented as well. (Granted in many cases you could use generics like `<T extends A & B & C>` but that might make things more complex if used often or with larger numbers of interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am still not clear, I have edited my question to give you more clarity.

Comment: @developer your example for question 1 isn't clear and doesn't show any enclosing or even hint at what you actually mean (in fact I suspect the second interface is what you mean with "enclosing interface" so there's no difference - besides the very likely wrong conception of "enclosing").

Comment: Can you provide an example for Nested vs Enclosing interface ?

Comment: @developer Consider `interface A { interface B { ... } }`. Here `A` would be the enclosing interface and `B` the nested one. In constrast to classes nested interfaces can't have a special relationship with their enclosing interface so they are implicitly static and the nesting acts more or less as some kind of namespace (e.g. you could nest another `B` inside some interface `C` and then could access them using `A.B` and `C.B` but they both are different from each other).